# implement onclick() in custom directive angular 4

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I have a simple button and a directive I want to access the button's style, add MarginLeft with an onclick() function in the directive it is not working but setting the css from constructor works how can I use this with on click? please help:

the directive:

```
    import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[Bluecolored]'
})
export class BluecoloredDirective {

  constructor(private element:ElementRef) {
    console.log(element);
   element.nativeElement.style.color="blue";
   }
clicked(){
  this.element.nativeElement.style.marginLeft=20;
  console.log("marzi"+this.element.nativeElement.style.marginLeft);
}
}
```

this is the template:

```
<p Bluecolored>
  new-fom works!
</p>
<h1 Bluecolored>Blue Colored</h1>
<button   (click)="clicked()" Bluecolored>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use a HostListener in your directive:

```
@HostListener('click') onClick(){
    this.element.nativeElement.style.marginLeft=20;
    console.log("marzi"+this.element.nativeElement.style.marginLeft);
}
```

this way you can remote `(click)="clicked()"` from the button aswell

I named mine onClick, but you could name it clicked aswell

Comment: but I want to select a particular element from the dom say a button, How can I do that?

Comment: HostListener only listens for events on the element the directive is bound to.

Comment: i was to late to edit my previous comment so,
if you want multiple elements to change on the click of a button you are probably better of using component and a variable controlling the styles of your element (or a variable toggling a class).

Comment: can we use @HostListener() from a component or is this only accessible from a directive??

Comment: yes, components extend directives, so all posibilities on directives are also possible on components, HostListener on a component will listen for events on the component element (e.g. <app-component></app-component>)

Comment: Not sure if this changed since you answered but should be `@HostListner('click')` to bind to the click event, rather than `onClick`.